# Change ViewController for a TabBarItem

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Is it possible to change/replace ViewContoller (and View) for one of the Tabs in a UITabBarController?

I would like to switch between 3 different ViewControllers in any order from a specific Tab (that´s why NavigationController is not possible).

Answer (score 3):

They are set (in mass) using setViewControllers:animated: so you could do something like this.

```
// Assume tabController is the tab controller 
// and newVC is the controller you want to be the new view controller at index 0
NSMutableArray *newControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tabController.viewControllers];
[newControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:newVC];
[tabController setViewControllers:newControllers animated:YES];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! It did replaced the ViewController. However the TabBarItem was restored and the icon/text was gone. 

I did this from within one of the ViewControllers belonging to a tabBarItem that may not be okay?