# Set ViewController for a specific Index in TabbarController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabbarController` with 5 `ViewControllers` as index number 0,1,2,3,4, Now, If its run in iPhone then 5 viewcontrollers loaded on it, that's fine, but if I changed iPhone to iPad, index number 4 should be different `ViewControllers`.

**Ex.**

```
if iPad{
    tabbarcontroller's index 4 should be B Viewcontroller
}else{
    tabbarcontroller's index 4 should be A Viewcontroller
}
```

I got an answer in objective c, [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303787/change-viewcontroller-for-a-tabbaritem) but I can not make it out for Swift, Here is my code:

```
let settingVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingTabbarController") as! SettingTabbarController

var controllers : NSMutableArray =  [self.viewControllers!][0] as! NSMutableArray

print(controllers)

controllers.replaceObject(at: 4, with: settingVc)

self.setViewControllers(controllers, animated: true)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your setting vc is also embedded in tabbar?

Comment: @PankajGupta No, ViewController 5 is embeded but i need it to be replaced with another viewcontroller for that index, which isn't embed.

Comment: @AbhishekMitra check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you can change the viewController for specific index like below

in your `UITabbarController`

```
   self.viewControllers?.remove(at: 4)
   let newItemController = UIStoryboard(name: "Settings", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsViewController") as! SettingsViewController
   newItemController.title = "Settings"
   newItemController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "ic_tab_settings")
   newItemController.tabBarItem.isEnabled = true
   self.viewControllers?.insert(newItemController, at:4)
```

Comment: Sorry for late replying, it working perfectly, very thanks.. :)

Comment: Here `let newItemController = UIStoryboard(name: "Settings", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsViewController") as! SettingsViewController
   newItemController.title = "Settings"`, I have changed `let newItemController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsViewController") as! SettingsViewController
   newItemController.title = "Settings"`

Comment: Don't usually do this but... works like a charm! Thank you!